# How can I extract the name directories from an attribute in Apache Nifi?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

How can I extract the name directories in Apache Nifi?
I want to extract the names from the 'absolute-path' attribute of the flowfiles, and save it like attributes of the same flowfile.

Ex: The value of the absolute.path is "C:\Users\01_SEG\2019"
and put them in new attributes like: year= 2019, time=01_SEG

I tried to use replaceAll function in the "UpdateAttribute" to extract info from the "absolute.path" but doesn't recognize me groups with the (). I don't know how manipulate groups inside regex in NiFi and attributes inside NiFi.
For example, I want to delete the last two names of directories, but doesn't work.

```
${'absolute.path':replaceAll('(\\[0-9]{2}_SEG)(\\([0-9]{4}\/)$)','')}
```

This expression works in any Java Regex, but here not.
If I try something like:

```
time = ${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".*\\(.*)\\\d{4}", "$1")}
```

There are errors like:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC3yQ.png)

Comment: Please show the code you used.

Comment: Thanks, know the code is available. @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UpdateAttribute`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/index.html) processor allows arbitrary new/existing attributes to have values assigned from [regular expression parsing](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replacefirst) via Expression Language of other attributes. Example for your scenario:

Existing attribute *absolute.path* = "C:\Users\01_SEG\2019"

Add dynamic properties for:

- *time* = `${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".+\\\\(\\w+)\\\\\\d{4}", "$1")}`
- *year* = `${"absolute.path":replaceFirst(".*(\d{4})$", "$1")}`

The resulting flowfile will have the following attributes:

- *absolute.path* = "C:\Users\01_SEG\2019"
- *time* = "01_SEG"
- *year* = "2019"

The extra quoting around attribute *absolute.path* in the expression is because it contains a `.` character.

**Update**

The slash escaping needed to be doubled because of the direction of the Windows slashes.

`$1` references "group 1" in the regular expression, so we are *extracting* whatever is contained within the group and then *replacing* the entire match (the whole original value) with just the contents of the group.

If you want the expression to be the same for both, you can specify an expression with two groups and replace it with `$1` for one attribute and `$2` for the other.

Output from running in a local environment just now:

```
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Wed Oct 07 10:37:39 PDT 2020'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Wed Oct 07 10:37:39 PDT 2020'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '0'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'absolute.path'
    Value: 'C:\Users\01_SEG\2019'
Key: 'filename'
    Value: 'b16c325e-6d21-4d54-82f6-971c47152d63'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'time'
    Value: '01_SEG'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: 'b16c325e-6d21-4d54-82f6-971c47152d63'
Key: 'year'
    Value: '2019'
--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry, but what is the second argument? "$1". I try, but there are errors.

Comment: Do you know how to put inside in a regex expression the value of some attribute? Also, want to use the "$" to work with the end of a line. I try use it but nifi give me back an error

Comment: Thank you! @Andy I use windows, I forget put that. One more question, if I want to match with a value of an attribute inside of regex, only use the expression '${nameAttribute}' ?

Comment: Yes, the expression language term to evaluate the value of an attribute should occur before the regular expression application, so that should work.